# Java streams adding multiple values conditionally

Tags: java, java-stream, bigdecimal

I have a List of objects like this, where amount can be negative or positive:

```
class Sale {
   String country;
   BigDecimal amount;
}
```

And I would like to end up with a pair of sums of all negative values, and all positive values, by country.

With these values:

```
country | amount
nl      | 9
nl      | -3
be      | 7.9
be      | -7
```

Is there a way to end up with `Map<String, Pair<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>>` using a single stream?

It's easy to do this with two separate streams, but I can't figure it out with just one.

Comment: So, your list only holds 4 items, 2 with positive values and 2 with negative values? Or can it potentially hold more or less data? If so, what values would the `Pair<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>` hold? I'm a bit confused on the value portion of your Map, by what it represents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be using `Collectors.toMap` with a merge function to sum pairs.

Assuming that a `Pair` is immutable and has only getters for the first and second elements, the code may look like this:

```java
static Map<String, Pair<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>> sumUp(List<Sale> list) {
    return list.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                   Sale::getCountry,
                   sale -> sale.getAmount().signum() >= 0 
                       ? new Pair<>(sale.getAmount(), BigDecimal.ZERO)
                       : new Pair<>(BigDecimal.ZERO, sale.getAmount()),
                   (pair1, pair2) -> new Pair<>(
                       pair1.getFirst().add(pair2.getFirst()),
                       pair1.getSecond().add(pair2.getSecond())
                   )
                   // , LinkedHashMap::new // optional parameter to keep insertion order
               ));
}
```

Test

```java
List<Sale> list = Arrays.asList(
    new Sale("us", new BigDecimal(100)),
    new Sale("uk", new BigDecimal(-10)),
    new Sale("us", new BigDecimal(-50)),
    new Sale("us", new BigDecimal(200)),
    new Sale("uk", new BigDecimal(333)),
    new Sale("uk", new BigDecimal(-70))
);

Map<String, Pair<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>> map = sumUp(list);

map.forEach((country, pair) -> 
    System.out.printf("%-4s|%s%n%-4s|%s%n", 
        country, pair.getFirst(), country, pair.getSecond()
));
```

Output

```
uk  |333
uk  |-80
us  |300
us  |-50
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution clouse to  Alex Rudenko's but using groupingBy and downstream collector:

```
Map<String, Pair<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>> map =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Sale::getCountry,
                   Collectors.mapping(s ->
                      s.getAmount().signum() >= 0?
                      new Pair<>(s.getAmount(), BigDecimal.ZERO):
                      new Pair<>(BigDecimal.ZERO, s.getAmount()),
                   Collectors.reducing(new Pair(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO),
                                       (p1, p2) -> new Pair(p1.getKey().add(p2.getKey()),
                                                            p1.getValue().add(p2.getValue()))))
        ));
```

Comment: The input list cannot be just grouped by country, there's no guarantee that there are exactly two `Sale` per country with positive and negative `amount`

Comment: Yes are right @Alex Rudenko. Let me think later.

Comment: @Alex Rudenko Anyway I came to solution close to yours. Thanx for help.